# Sitemesh with spring security is not redirecting to target url

Tags: spring-security, sitemesh

I am integrating spring security with my web project which uses sitemesh. I am able to bring the login page but after authentication it is not redirecting to target-url.

Below is my web.xml from web project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext-persistance.xml
    classpath*:applicationContext.xml
    classpath:spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!--    
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.app</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
-->
<!-- <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
-->

<!-- Sitemesh -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> -->

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>-- > 
</web-app>
```

Below is spring-security.xml from AppSecurity project.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

  <security:form-login login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/index.html" always-use-default-target="true"   
               authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="postSuccessAuthHandler" />

  <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/app" />

  <!-- <security:remember-me /> -->
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/app" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/acct/app"
       access="isAuthenticated()" /> -->

</security:http>

<!--<bean id="postSuccessAuthHandler"
class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthentication          SuccessHandler">
<property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html" />-->
```

I have my loginpage.jsp is in webapp\WEB-INF\views, which is decorated by sitemesh -

```
<div id="mainNav"><div class="navWrapper">
    <ul>
    <li class="${fn:startsWith(menuPath, 'M')? 'selected':'first'}"><a     
       href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html"><spring:message  
       code="mnu.home" /></a></li>
```

LoginController.java which handles this is  -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
   return "loginpage";
}
```

So the issue here is on accessing the url - http://localhost:8080/acct/app, it shows login page. After successful authentication it's trying to redirect to http://localhost:8080/acct/app. Not sure why it happens instead of to */index.html* as mentioned in *default-target-url*.

Log lines from tomcat shows -

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for
 [/acct/login]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapping [/login] to HandlerExecutionCh
ain with handler [com.mycomp.security.controller.LoginController@1e5348f] and 2 interceptors
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/acct/login] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker - Invoking request handler method: public java.lan
g.String com.mycomp.security.controller.LoginController.login(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name
 'loginpage'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/loginpage.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/loginpage.jsp] in InternalResour
ceView 'loginpage'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for
 [/acct/app]
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/acct/app] in DispatcherServ
let with name 'appServlet'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for
 [/acct/app]
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/acct/app] in DispatcherServ
let with name 'appServlet'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Tried debugging a lot by changing the DispatcherServlet mapping to / instead of /index.html. Changing sitemesh filter-mapping to /* instead of /index.html. 
Same AppSecurity project works fine if integrated with sample web project(without sitemesh). 
Not sure what i am missing here in sitemesh project. Any help would be great here.

Answer (score 1):

`"default-target-url=/index.html"` this will redirect the page after you have success login.
for example you can to redirect to `/home.html` or used `/home.do` in the controller to do some logic before you want to redirect to the page you want.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(ModelMap model) {

   //TODO logic ...
   return "/home.html";
}
```